# Cleanly and optionally redirect stderr or stdout to file

Tags: python-3.x, stream, control-flow, contextmanager, exception-safety

I have a Python3 script and I want to optionally redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a file. Something like this:

```
# variable declarations
if log_output:
    output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')
    sys.stdout = output_file

if log_errors:
    errors_file = open('errors.txt', 'w')
    sys.stderr = errors_file

# code that uses variables declared above but may exit suddenly

#at the end
if log_output:
    output_file.close()

if log_errors:
    errors_file.close()
```

This works, unless my code in the middle decides to quit. Then my files aren't guaranteed to be closed. How can I cleanly close these files no matter what happens in the code and only some of the time? (Normally, I would redirect through the shell, but I'm computing the file names in Python and I don't want to recompute them in various shells. Also, I don't want to put the logic for whether or not to redirect in a shell script. I want those branches in my main code if possible.)

### Attempt 1

It seems like context managers would be the way to here, but, when I try to use them, I have to rewrite my code several times and it's not pretty code:

```
if log_output:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(output_file):
            if log_errors:
                with open('errors.txt','w') as errors_file:
                    with contextlib.redirect_stderr(errors_file):
                        # log_output and log_errors
                        # code that uses variables declared above but may exit suddenly
            else:
                # log_output and not log_errors
                # code that uses variables declared above but may exit suddenly
else:
    if log_errors:
        with open('errors.txt', 'w') as errors_file:
            with contextlib.redirect_stderr(errors_file):
                # not log_output and log_errors
                # code that uses variables declared above but may exit suddenly
    else:
        # not log_output and not log_errors
        # code that uses variables declared above but may exit suddenly
```

### Attempt 2

I decided to make a context manager for it. I think it works, and Python's not yelling at me, but I still can't help but feel it's not too Pythonic and I'm not completely sure it's safe. I'm pushing the `if` statements in odd directions. Is there a better way?

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def opt_stream(stream, name = None):
    if name:
        file = open(name,'w')
        yield file
        file.close()
    else:
        yield stream

output_name, errors_name = None, None

if log_output:
    output_name = 'outputs.txt'
if log_errors:
    errors_name = 'errors.txt'

with opt_stream(sys.stdout, output_name) as output_file:
    with opt_stream(sys.stderr, errors_name) as errors_file:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(output_file):
            with contextlib.redirect_stderr(errors_file):
                # code that uses variables declared above but may exit suddenly
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The cleanest way to optionally redirect your program's `stdout` or `stderr` to a file is to not do so in your program at all.  Instead, do it through your operating system's shell.</strike>

On Linux, if I wanted to redirect a Python program's `stdout` to a file, [I'd do this](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-redirection.html):

```
$ python something.py > stdout.log
$ python something_else.py 2> stderr.log
```

Note the `2>` for redirecting `stderr` output.

As it happens, [`cmd`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and [PowerShell](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html) on Windows use the same syntax.

---

The above, while true, isn't relevant given the OP's updated problem description.

Assuming you're using Python 3, [the built-in `print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) actually has a named parameter "`file`" that lets you decide where to `print` to.

```
print(some_object, file=your_own_file_object)
```

`file` can be any file-like object (which `stdout` and `stderr` are).  You could just pass in the result of [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), or get crazy and screw around with the [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).  Whatever the case, you just have to maintain a variable (whose value is possibly that of `sys.stdout`) and always pass that in to `print` calls, and then just set that variable whenever you decide where to output something to.

Otherwise, you might considering setting the value of [`sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout), if you don't mind getting funny looks from other Python programmers.

Comment: Normally I would love to simplify it that way, but in the real code, I'm going to redirect the streams to file names computed by the program. I don't want to have to re-compute those file names outside the program for redirection purposes.

Comment: Could you please update your question to reflect that, then?  Also, how are these file names computed?

Comment: I updated the question about redirecting the stream from the shell. The file names are from a configuration file with names and a log folder. I don't want to have to write a big shell script with logic of its own to  read the config and join the log folder name with the file name.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Updated answer incoming.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, but those aren't exception safe. I have to open a file that's not guaranteed to be closed unless I use a with statement, which opens a file regardless of whether or not I actually want to. I'm simply going to use my last version, and document it well. Thanks again.